# Ignore exceptions while converting a @RequestParam value

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an endpoint that takes a request parameter: `http://localhost/test?parameter=123`
When somebody calls this endpoint with a string instead of an integer he gets a BAD_REQUEST response because the string can not be converted.

Is it possible to ignore conversion exceptions on a request parameter and just leave it empty?`

Currently my code looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public void doSomething(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer parameter) {...}
```

Comment: Why not taking the parameter simply as String and convert yourself in the method code?

Answer (score 1):

You should take the parameter as String and convert yourself.

By saying it should be `Integer` in your method signature you require this indeed to be an integer. If it was not it is indeed `BAD_REQUEST`. If you want other custom scenario you should implement it yourself.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public void doSomething(@RequestParam(required = false) String parameter) {

    Integer parameterValue = null;

    if (parameter != null) {
        try {
           parameterValue = Integer.valueOf(parameter);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
           // No-op as already null
        }
    }

    // At this point the parameterValue is either null if not specified or specified as non-int, or has the integer value in it
}
```